# Is latest RCPTT 2.5.2 supports NatTable?

Tags: eclipse, automated-tests, nattable, nebula, eclipse-rcptt

I need to add some RCPTT testcases on [Nebula NatTable](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/).

I tried RCPTT with version 2.3.0 and 2.5.2 nightly build but not able to capture table data. Please let me know if RCPTT supports NatTable or even if there is any workaround to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately, no: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1092576/ The NatTable support is obviously needed by some, but none of them have contributed or sponsored it. Either they don't know how open source works or it wasn't that important to them.

Comment: I thought so. I also visited that thread. No update since last 2 years. Thanks for replying @howlger